# Austrian embassy asking for old passport for visa

Tags: schengen

The documents checklist at the Austrian embassy page for Schengen visa says I need to submit all the old passports as well for the visa. I have been issued 4 passports in my lifetime. 3 of them are expired.

I have the current one and the last two passports. However I have misplaced the first passport, which was issued when I was 5 years old. Should I just write in my cover letter that that passport was misplaced or should I file a police complaint? The lost passport expired 12 years ago and was not used to travel outside the country at any time. (India)

Comment: I don't think there is any need to file a police complaint for a passport that expired 12 years ago. I would mention the situation in the cover letter. Old passport loss is not something unheard of

Comment: Pls. read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81983/lost-my-old-passport-for-schengen-visa-application?rq=1

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. The last 10-15 years is usually okay.